# How to decide whether a document actually uses pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, paper-size

Let's say our system-wide default paper size is A4, and we have an old 15-pages-long document (prepared using llncs class) which we don't completely understand at this moment (neither content-wise nor LaTeX-wise). In the preamble we see `\usepackage{pst-node}`.  With or without this line the document runs smoothly through `latex`; the log shows no errors, warnings or reports about undefined or missing stuff.  Still, comparing the PDF files from the two runs (with/without pstricks) by `diffpdf` results in visual differences *everywhere* and word differences as well as character differences *nowhere*.

As a minimal example, let's run

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{llncs}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

through `latex` followed by `dvipdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY`.  The visual comparison of the results when `pstricks` is vs. is not used by `diffpdf` results in this:

[image: comparison results]

The two red bars on the left mark the changes. As these red bars are everywhere, this leaves us with no information whatsoever concerning whether pstricks is actually needed by the document.

1. Why does simply including a drawing package but not actually drawing anything incur such global changes?  Who is the culprit?
2. How to check whether pstricks is needed or used (and if so, where or how) without manually inspecting 15 pages and trying to understand commands and contents we have little idea of? (This could be an endeavor of several hours till a week: the paper is a typical computer-science paper.)

Comment: If you remove `pstricks`, compile the document, and get no "Undefined control sequence" errors, then it's highly unlikely that you were actually using `pstricks`.

Comment: instead of `latex` and `dvipdf` simply run `lualatex`,  then there should be no difference

Comment: @user187802 lualatex would use different fonts (latin modern OpenType rather than Computer Modern Type1)

Comment: Sure, but this is not the problem here ...

Comment: @user187802 In fact, after running lualatex on both files, there is a difference. (If you get different results, then, probably, your system-wide default could be letter.) In fact, commenting out pstricks, running `lualatex mwe.tex`, and then `pdfinfo mwe.pdf`, we get  `Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)`. The class option `[letterpaper]` has seemingly no effect!!!

Comment: the paper size options a4paper or letterpaper of the standard classes do not directly affect the media size in the pdf. (only if color or graphics or hyperref or geometry etc is used)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  - huh, and people wonder why latex newcomers find this system - in 2022 - difficult to learn/use (One example of many.)

Comment: @davidbak if you say so. `letterpaper` adjusts the text bock for US paper, but f you print it anywhere else, on a A4 paper it does what people expect. the pdf media box is like the paper tray in your printer, it is a site settable default.

Answer (score 5):

A document that gives no error if you comment out the `\usepackage` is highly unlikely to be using pstricks in any essential way but...

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{llncs}
\pagestyle{empty}
\showoutput
%\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

If you run this with and without `pstricks` the `\showoutput` box logging (a visual representation of the dvi generated)  shows the following diff

```
369,372d178
< ..\special{header=pstricks.pro}
< ..\special{header=pst-algparser.pro}
< ..\special{header=pst-tools.pro}
< ..\special{header=pst-dots.pro}
374d179
< ..\special{papersize=614.295pt,794.96999pt}
380d184
< ....\special{color push gray 0}
382d185
< ....\special{color pop}
387,393d189
< ...\special{color push gray 0}
< ...\special{ps: /pssetRGBcolor /setrgbcolor load def /pssetCMYKcolor /setcmykco
< lo\ETC.}
< ...\special{ps:tx@Dict begin  gsave STV CP T /ps@rot 0 def grestore  end}
< ...\special{ps:tx@Dict begin  gsave STV CP T /ps@refangle 0.  def grestore  end
< }
< ...\special{ps:0.8 setlinewidth 0 setgray}
408d203
< ...\special{color push gray 0}
410d204
< ...\special{color pop}
```

So the dvi has a bunch of additional (dvips syntax) `\special`s.

If you use a different dvi driver these specials may be ignored or interpreted depending on the dvi driver used.

The first four `header` specials are including PostScript source, these are almost certainly ignored if not using dvips

The `papersize` special is setting the media size and will affect the media box in generated pdf if the dvi driver used supports that

The `ps:` specials are dvips syntax to inject literal PostScript code, and are probably ignored by other drivers

The other specials are related to color and may or may not be ignored depending on the dvi driver used, but are just setting black, so would not have a visible effect

Comment: Thanks! Changing the paper size manually in the postscript might probably be insufficient; see my own answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656385 to this question.

Comment: I also ran into another bug/feature/issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656324/how-to-decide-whether-a-document-actually-uses-pstricks/656385#comment1635553_656324 .

Answer (score 1):

As for the minimal document in question:

- Changing the `[letterpaper]` class option to `[a4paper]` temporarily for the purpose of comparison does the trick: after the change, running `diffpdf` on the two results from `latex` followed by `dvipdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` yields no differences in any of the three modes (visual, character, words).
- Alternatively, `dvips -t letter -Ppdf -q -f infile.dvi | gs -q -P- -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=outfile.pdf -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY -` produces the PDF file with the `[letterpaper]` class option. Do it once for each `infile.dvi` (one generated with pstricks, another without) and compare the resulting PDF file.

As for the real, 15-page-long non-minimal document (which we have not provided the reader with), we still see differences *everywhere* regardless of whether we use the `[a4paper]` class option or try to generate the letter PDF file. (This is, however, beyond the scope of the question as it is stands now.) It turned out that `\usepackage{color}` was the culprit: this package turned out to be unnecessary for the document, and not including it made the differences in using vs. not using pstricks go away.

Comment: I can't see how  this answer can be right, pstricks includes xcolor

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The observation is: we have `\usepackage{color}\usepackage{pst-node}` in the preamble of a non-minimal, 15-page-long document; dropping both packages yields a PDF file which `diffpdf` cannot distinguish from the original and from the output produced with `\usepackage{pst-node}` but without `\usepackage{color}`. I don't know why.